# jQuery Star Rating Plugin how to switch from disabled to enabled on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using [this](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/) plugin for rating on my website. Now when I load my view and the user has already posted a rating the rating is displayed by making the value selected by user `checked`. 
What I am unable to achieve is to enable the rating when the user clicks the edit button (div). The issue is that the plugin hides the original radio buttons and replaces them with:

```
<div role="text" aria-label="Bad"
class="star-rating rater-0 star star-rating-applied
star-rating-readonly star-rating-on">
  <a title="Bad">2</a>
</div>
```

As you can see a part of the class says `readonly`. When the rating is live the code looks like this:

```
<div role="text" aria-label="Bad" 
class="star-rating rater-0 star star-rating-applied 
star-rating-live">
  <a title="Bad">2</a>
</div>
```

These divs are generated five times as I have 5 original radio buttons. I have tried replacing the `readonly` class with the `live` class, but I still wasn't able to use the rating. Please, if anyone here has a clue how to achieve this, let me know. Thank you for reading and in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 2):

Always read the documentation first before asking questions.

set the readOnly to false so you can change the rating.
eg.: `$('input').rating('readOnly',false)` or simply `$('input').rating('readOnly');`

you have to change the word input with the name of your css selector

```
$('input') to eg: $('.star')
```

[source](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/)

Answer (score 1):

Got it. The issue was that I was creating the rating like this:





so it is read only by default. So then when I tried to make it active with a function(`$('input').rating('readOnly',false);` it wouldn't work. So **now I create the elements without the `disabled` attribute and use this script:**

```
            <script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('input').rating('readOnly');
                $( "#edit" ).click(function() {

                    $('input').rating('readOnly',false);

                    $('textarea').removeAttr('disabled');
                    $('textarea').select();
                });
            });
            </script>
```

Comment: was the answer helpful ?